# Como comparar se dois objetos javascript são iguais?

Tags: javascript

Sabemos que se eu tiver dois objetos criados em variáveis distintas, porem com mesmo conteúdo, ao fazer a comparação, o javascript irá retornar false.

**Exemplo**

```
var objA = {a:'teste'}
var objB = {a:'teste'}

if (objA === objB) {...} // return false
if (objA == objB) {...} // return false
```

Então como faço para saber se os dois objetos são iguais?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Não há maneira simples de se fazer isso em JavaScript, pois internamente a linguagem tem dois tipos de abordagem pra testar igualdades. Dados primitivos como strings e numerais são comparados pelo seu valor, enquanto objetos, arrays e datas são comparados pela sua referência. Essa comparação de referência basicamente checa se o dado objeto é referido pelo mesmo espaço em memória.

Mas aqui vai uma abordagem básica de como checar a equivalência de objetos:

```
function isEquivalent(a, b) {
    // Create arrays of property names
    var aProps = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(a);
    var bProps = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(b);

    // If number of properties is different,
    // objects are not equivalent
    if (aProps.length != bProps.length) {
        return false;
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < aProps.length; i++) {
        var propName = aProps[i];

        // If values of same property are not equal,
        // objects are not equivalent
        if (a[propName] !== b[propName]) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    // If we made it this far, objects
    // are considered equivalent
    return true;
}
```

Fonte: http://adripofjavascript.com/blog/drips/object-equality-in-javascript.html

Comment: Vale lembrar que essa função não funcionaria com um objeto dentro de outro objeto. Algo como a comparação de `var pessoa1 = { "nome" : "Maria", "curso" : { "nome" : "Dreamweaver", "ano" : "2008" } }` e `var pessoa2 = { "nome" : "Maria", "curso" : { "nome" : "Dreamweaver", "ano" : "2008" } }`. O método `isEquivalent` retorna `false` mesmo sendo iguais.

Answer (score 13):

Uma ótima pergunta, Rodrigo! Vou responder à sua pergunta melhorando dois dos códigos já feitos pelos colegas, também te passando algumas outras informações sobre JavaScript. Ao final, vou te mostrar uma solução própria minha, unindo tudo o que lhe passei.

Infelizmente, ao contrário de algumas outras linguagens, JavaScript não possui o método "equals" (como C# ou Java). Além disso, essa linguagem possui dois pares distintos de operadores de igualdade.

**=== e !==**

Funcionam como normalmente se esperaria; se os dois lados da igualdade são do mesmo tipo e possuem o mesmo valor, então o resultado é verdadeiro. Caso contrário, retorna falso.

**== e !=**

JavaScript fará uma coerção de valor entre os dois lados da igualdade, sem verificar o tipo. Caso tenham o mesmo valor, retornará verdadeiro. Caso contrário, retornará falso. Porém, deve-se tomar muito cuidado com esses, pois eles fazem uma verificação muito superficial e muitas vezes você pode acabar com um resultado indesejável.

Na dúvida, **use sempre o primeiro par**.

Em ambas as suas comparações realizadas o valor retornado foi falso, pois o que você está tentando comparar é um objeto complexo, e ele possui somente a referência para o objeto armazenada na variável: logo, os objetos possuem referências diferentes e são *objetos diferentes*. Se fossem valores literais, a comparação direta seria possível.

Agora, para a real resposta da sua pergunta: como JavaScript não possui um método específico para a comparação de objetos, e até mesmo os melhores operadores de igualdade (**=== e !==**) não funcionam com objetos complexos, é necessário fazer um método para comparação nós mesmos.

Porém, *quais os problemas com os códigos apresentados acima?*

**Código 1**

Esse código tem a infeliz questão de que ele não verifica se esse objeto possui, internamente, outros objetos. Então, caso ele acabe encontrando um objeto dentro do que está sendo verificado, ele irá verificar somente as referências (como informei anteriormente), e o resultado será falso, mesmo se ambos forem realmente iguais. Realizei alguns comentários no código para mostrar os problemas e as qualidades.

```
function isEquivalent(a, b) {
    // Acredito que essa seja uma das qualidades do código.
    // É realizada a verificação do que o objeto possui internamente, e isso
    // é passado diretamente para a variável.
    var aProps = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(a);
    var bProps = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(b);

    // Então, é feita a verificação se os dois objetos possuem o mesmo
    // número de propriedades. Muito bom! E tira muito trabalho caso não
    // tenham.
    if (aProps.length != bProps.length) {
        return false;
    }

    // Caso tenham o mesmo número, é realizada uma iteração por todas as
    // propriedades do objeto. Porém, como ressaltei antes, não busca por
    // objetos dentro de objetos, podendo retornar uma inconsistência.
    for (var i = 0; i < aProps.length; i++) {
        var propName = aProps[i];

        if (a[propName] !== b[propName]) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

**Código 2**

Bom, esse código está simplesmente muito confuso. Ele não faz uma verificação óbvia das propriedades dos objetos (como o anterior fazia), e ele usa muitos if, tornando difícil a leitura e o entendimento do código. Além do mais, ele utiliza, no seu interior, os operadores de igualdade que comparam somente o valor (o que pode levar a inconsistências, dependendo do valor comparado!). Porém, não entendi muito bem como ele funciona. Assim como no anterior, fiz alguns comentários sobre o código (com o que pude entender):

```
function deepEqual(obj1 , obj2 , profund){
    // Nesse primeiro if, ele está verificando se os dois objetos são, realmente,
    // objects, além de fazer a comparação obj1 != obj2, que sempre retornará false,
    // a não ser que sejam valores literais e sejam iguais.
    // Desnecessário.
    if(typeof(obj1) == "object" && typeof(obj2)=='object' && obj1 != obj2){
    // Aqui, ele pega as propriedades dos dois objetos e verifica se possuem
    // a mesma quantidade, porém não as armazena em local algum.
       if(Object.keys(obj1).length == Object.keys(obj2).length){
    // Aqui, está realizando um for in, que passa por todas as propriedades
    // do objeto, inclusive os prototype. Pode dar algum resultado errado!
            for (var prop in obj1) {                                     

                if ((prop in obj2)){
    // Aqui, ele realiza a comparação dos dois objetos.
                    if(profund == true && obj1[prop] != obj2[prop]){
                        return false;
                        break
                    }else if(profund == false){
                        return true
                        break
                    }                   
                }             
            }
        return true;    
       }

    }else{
        return (obj1 === obj2);
    }
}
```

Agora, ***finalmente***, o código que eu acredito ser o melhor para a comparação completa de objetos complexos. Fiz isso usando algumas técnicas que aprendi no livro [The Good Parts](https://7chan.org/pr/src/OReilly_JavaScript_The_Good_Parts_May_2008.pdf), do Douglas Crockford. Recomendo muito a leitura! Será um código muitíssimo parecido com o **Código 1**, porém com a melhoria que acredito que faltava nele. Utilizo, para isso, uma das melhores coisas criadas na história da computação: a recursividade! Segue abaixo o código com comentários.

```
var equals = function (object1, object2) {
    // Realiza a verificação das propriedades dos objetos.
    var prop1 = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(object1);
    var prop2 = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(object1);

    // Realiza a verificação se ambos objetos possuem o mesmo número de 
    // propriedades. Caso contrário, já retorna dizendo que são diferentes.
    if(prop1.length !== prop2.length)
        return false;

    // Aqui, está sendo verificado se o objeto possui alguma propriedade.
    // Será usado quando for chamada a função na sua forma recursiva,
    // para verificar valores literais.
    if(prop1.length === 0)
        if(object1 === object2)
            return true;
        else
            return false;

    // Se forem iguais, realiza uma iteração por todas as propriedades.
    for(var i = 0; i < prop1.length; i++) {
    // Guarda o valor da propriedade atual na variável "prop".
        var prop = prop1[i];

    // Aqui está o pulo do gato.
    // Verifica se o valor e o tipo das duas propriedades são iguais.
    // Se sim, somente pula para a próxima iteração. Caso contrário,
    // podem ser duas coisas: ou são realmente distintos, ou é um objeto,
    // que, ao comparar as referências, retorna sempre falso.
    // Para ter certeza da informação, é chamada a mesma função de forma
    // recursiva, mandando, por parâmetro, os dois objetos que ficou a dúvida.
    // Se forem iguais, ou se tiverem mais algum objeto internamente, 
    // a função continuará a ser chamada recursivamente, até chegar ao
    // ponto de ser um valor literal. Ou, então, retornará falso, pois não
    // são iguais.
    // Caso sejam iguais, a função só continuará para a próxima iteração.
    // Caso contrário, a função já informa que não são dois objetos iguais.
        if(object1[prop] !== object2[prop]){
            if(equals(object1[prop], object2[prop]))
                continue;
            else
                return false;
        }
    }
    // Se chegou até aqui e aguentou todas as verificações...
    // Os objetos são iguais!
    return true;
}
```

Era isso por hoje! Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Muito legal a sua resposta, grato pela colaboração.

Comment: Gostei de como lidou com o problema, mas sua função falharia neste caso: `console.log( equals({ y: [] }, { y: [] }) );` ou `console.log( equals({ y: {} }, { y: {} ) );`, o problema acontece porque ao verificar `if(object1 === object2)` quando o **prop1.length** é igual a **0**, neste caso de objeto vazios, irá verificar a referencia deles, e se não estiverem no mesmo lugar na memória, serão diferentes. A maneira para resolver este caso, seria mudar `if(object1 === object2)` para `if(object1 === object2 || (typeof prop1 === "object" || typeof prop2 === "object"))`.

Comment: Eu usaria uma função assim para verificar quando são objetos vazios([] e {}), lembrando que em javascript um Array é um objeto: `const isObjectOrArray = (obj) => {
    return (typeof obj === "object" && obj !== null);
};` a verificação `obj !== null` é necessária pois **null** é retornado como "object".

Comment: Encontrei outra falha, em objetos com chaves diferentes, ex: `const obj1 = { Comp1: { x: 0, y: 0 } };
const obj2 = { Comp2: { width: 0, height: 0 } };`, irá receber um erro ao atribuir `var prop2 = ...` mas isso pode ser evitado comparando os seus `typeof` ao entrar na funçao `if(typeof object1 !== typeof object2){return false;}`

Answer (score 7):

A mesma lógica da outra resposta utilizando [es6](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Suporte_ao_ECMAScript_6_na_Mozilla) (versão mais moderna do javascript):

```
function saoIguais(objetoA, objetoB) {

    //Busca as chaves do objetoA e objetoB
    //utilizando o "let" o escopo da variável é limitado para o bloco.
    //Object.keys retornará um array com todas as chaves do objeto.
    let aChaves = Object.keys(objetoA),
        bChaves = Object.keys(objetoB);

    //Compara os tamanhos, se forem diferentes retorna falso pois 
    //o numero de propriedades é diferente, logo os objetos são diferentes
    if (aChaves.length != bChaves.length) {
        return false;
    }

    //Verifico se existe algum elemento com valor diferente nos objetos.
    //o array.some executa uma função(passada por parâmetro) para cada valor
    //do array. Essa função deve executar um teste, se para algum dos valores
    //o teste é verdadeiro, a execução é interrompida e true é retornado.
    //Do contrário, se o teste nunca for verdadeiro ele retornará false 
    //após executar o teste para todos valores do array.
    //Estou basicamente verficando se existe diferença entre dois valores do objeto.

    let saoDiferentes = aChaves.some((chave) => {
        return objetoA[chave] !== objetoB[chave];
    });

    //como saoDiferentes contém true caso os objetos sejam diferentes eu 
    //simplesmente nego esse valor para retornar que os objetos são iguais (ou não).
    return !saoDiferentes;
}
```

Documentação do [Array.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some).

ES6 traz novos recursos e melhorias para o javascript. Você pode conferir mais sobre ele [aqui](https://medium.com/@matheusml/o-guia-do-es6-tudo-que-voc%C3%AA-precisa-saber-8c287876325f). (Já existem versões ainda mais recentes, veja [aqui](https://braziljs.org/blog/alguns-novos-recursos-es7-es8/)).

Particularmente recomendo estudar pois existem algumas coisas bem interessantes. Nas versões mais novas existem correções de problemas que existiam na linguagem, melhoria em questões de legibilidade e performance.

Comment: Olá Julio! A tua resposta está  em Inglês e o código não está comentado. Dificilmente ela será útil a alguém que está a aprender. Podes dar uma melhorada ou apagar?

Comment: Olá Sergio. Alterado.

Comment: `return objetoA[value] !== objetoB[value];` Não seria `chave` em vez de `value`?

Comment: bem notado, fiz algumas alterações para deixar o código mais legível e acabei esquecendo desse detalhe. Obrigado por avisar :)

Answer (score 4):

Converte ambos para uma string JSON e faz a comparação de strings:

```js
function compareObjects(obj1, obj2) {
  return JSON.stringify(obj1) === JSON.stringify(obj2);
}
```

Porém caso os objetos estejam com o atributos em ordens diferentes isso irá falhar, recomendo utilizar o isEqual do lodash (https://lodash.com/docs/#isEqual).

Answer (score -1):

```
    function isEqual(A, B) {
      let keys = Object.keys(A).concat(Object.keys(B));
      keys = [...new Set(keys)];

      for (let key of keys) {
        if (
          typeof A[key] !== typeof B[key] ||
          typeof A[key] !== 'object' && A[key] !== B[key] ||
          typeof A[key] === 'object' && !isEqual(A[key], B[key])
        ) {
          return false;
        }
      }

      return true;
    }
```

Esta função pode verificar de forma recursiva objetos dentro de objetos.

Answer (score -2):

eu fiz uma variação dos códigos acima que me parece mais completa:

```
function objetosSaoIguais( objeto1, objeto2 ) {

    if(objeto1 == null && objeto2 == null) return true;

    if(objeto1 == null || objeto2 == null || objeto1.length !== objeto2.length){
        return false;
    }

    for(let propriedade in objeto1){
    
        if(typeof objeto1[propriedade] === 'object' && typeof objeto2[propriedade] === 'object'){
            const saoIguais = objetosSaoIguais(objeto1[propriedade], objeto2[propriedade])
            if(!saoIguais) return false;
            continue
        }

        if(objeto1[propriedade] !== objeto2[propriedade]){
            return false
        }
    }
    return true;
}
const objeto1 = { nome: 'nome', teste: { nome: 'nome', teste2: {nome: 'igual'}}}
const objeto2 = { nome: 'nome', teste: { nome: 'nome',teste2: {nome:'igual'}}}
const objeto3 = { nome: 'nome', teste: { nome: 'nome',teste2: {nome:'diferente'}}}

console.log(objetosSaoIguais(objeto1, objeto2));
console.log(objetosSaoIguais(objeto1, objeto3))
```

Foi feita a verificação se o objeto é null pra não gerar erros, e caso sejam objetos aninhados será feito uma recursiva verificando esses objetos, retornando true para iguais e false para não iguais, e por ser usado o for in, irá verificar inclusive arrays

Answer (score -3):

Não daria para ser assim?

```
function nomeDaFuncao(obj1, obj2) {
    return obj1.key1 === obj2.key1 &&
           obj1.key2 === obj2.key2 
}
console.log(nomeDaFuncao(obj1, obj2));
```

Comment: Se os objetos orem gerados automaticamente e tiverem umas 1000 propriedades?