# Comparar objetos com array de objetos

Tags: javascript

Vou tentar ser prático. Por exemplo, tenho os seguintes objetos:

```
let a = {
  'before': 'small',
  'after': 'large',
  'type': 'size'
}

let b = [
  {
    'before': 'small',
    'after': 'large',
    'type': 'size'
  },
  {
    'before': 'large',
    'after': 'small',
    'type': 'size'
  }
]
```

Eu preciso compará-los, mas como o segundo é um array de objetos, eu preciso "desmembrá-lo" desse array, para que sejam outros dois objetos, assim eu comparo os três e retorno o diferente e a quantidade de objetos diferentes, que nesse caso é um, mas podem vir inúmeros casos diferentes. Eu não sei qual a melhor forma de fazer isso, se é transformando em arrays e comparando índices, ou se tem uma forma de comparar como objeto mesmo.

Comment: Tem uma pergunta parecida aqui, vê se lhe ajuda: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/291203/como-comparar-se-dois-objetos-javascript-s%C3%A3o-iguais

Comment: Ajuda até certo ponto, o problema começa quando eu tenho um array de objetos para comparar, então não sei se é possível desmembrar esse array em dois objetos.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar a lib [Lodash](https://lodash.com/).

[`_.isEqual(value, other)`](https://lodash.com/docs#isEqual)

Executa uma comparação profunda entre dois valores para determinar se eles são equivalentes.

> **Nota**: Este método suporta a comparação de matrizes, buffers de matriz,
>   booleanos, objetos de data, objetos de erro, mapas, números,
>   objetos, expressões regulares, conjuntos, cadeias, símbolos e
>   matrizes digitadas. Objetos são comparados por suas próprias
>   propriedades, não herdáveis ​​e enumeráveis. Funções e nós DOM são
>   comparados por igualdade estrita, `ie ===`.
>   Fonte: https://lodash.com/docs#isEqual

**Exemplo**

```js
let a = {
  'before': 'small',
  'after': 'large',
  'type': 'size'
}

let b = [{
    'before': 'small',
    'after': 'large',
    'type': 'size'
  },
  {
    'before': 'large',
    'after': 'small',
    'type': 'size'
  }
]
console.log(_.isEqual(a, b));

let c = {
  'before': 'small',
  'after': 'large',
  'type': 'size'
}

let d = {
    'before': 'small',
    'after': 'large',
    'type': 'size'
  }
console.log(_.isEqual(c, d));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Eu fiz esse exemplo no [codepen](https://codepen.io/mrdibre/pen/Ooeadb?editors=0010) de como ficaria o código.

Mas o que você precisaria fazer é apenas isso:

```
b.filter( item => JSON.stringify(item) !== JSON.stringify(a) )
```

Answer (score -2):

isso aqui deve funcionar

```
function findDiff(arr,obj){
let diff=[]
arr.forEach((Obj)=>{
if(JSON.stringify(Obj)!=JSON.stringify(obj))diff.push(Obj)
})
return diff
}
```

nesse caso basta chamar a função com `findDiff(b,a)` e então retornará um array de todos os objetos que são diferentes do segundo parametro

para pegar a quantidade de objetos diferentes como você disse é só usar a propriedade `.length`

exemplo:

```
let diferentes=findDiff(b,a)
console.log(diferentes.length)
```

Comment: Essa linha `if(Obj!=obj)diff.push(Obj)` não realiza o que você pensa que faz.  Em javascript os operadores de igualdade `==`e `!=` usam o [Algoritmo de Comparação de Igualdade Abstrata](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.3) para comparar dois operandos e segundo esse algoritmo se os operandos forem ambos de [tipos não primitivos](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Glossary/Primitive) a comparação é feita exclusivamente comparando as suas referências, portanto não são feitas comparações entre suas propriedades. Analise em seu código https://ideone.com/PZrNRF

Comment: Agora é essa linha `if(JSON.stringify(Obj)!=JSON.stringify(obj))diff.push(Obj)` que não faz o você espera. Ò mesmo problema dessa [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/332171/137387), além da limitações do método [JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) que da maneira usada não permitem comparações confiáveis entre objetos literais. Dois objetos que contenham as mesmas chaves e valores podem ser tidos como diferentes, veja no seu código https://ideone.com/DYo6jG